# Getting the background color of an ImageView

Tags: android, colors, imageview

I have a plain `ImageView` object `colorSquare`.

It is straightforward to set the color of the object by calling.

```
colorSquare.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

But how do I do the reverse, i.e. retrieve the color of the ImageView background?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What u can do is

get ColorDrawable from ImageView.

```
ColorDrawable drawable = (ColorDrawable) colorSquare.getBackground();
```

now

`drawable.getColor()`

will give u the Color.

This will work only if u have set the Color or else u will get ClassCastException

Answer (score -2):

```
private int colorfindcolor(View v, int x, int y) {


    int offset = 1; // 3x3 Matrix
    int pixelsNumber = 0;

    int xImage = 0;
    int yImage = 0;


    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.palette_color);
    xImage = (int) (x * ((double) imageBitmap.getWidth() / (double) paletteImg
            .getWidth()));
    yImage = (int) (y * ((double) imageBitmap.getHeight() / (double) paletteImg
            .getHeight()));

    for (int i = xImage - offset; i <= xImage + offset; i++) {
        for (int j = yImage - offset; j <= yImage + offset; j++) {
            try {

                color = imageBitmap.getPixel(i, j);

                pixelsNumber += 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.w(TAG, "Error picking color!");
            }
        }
    }

    return color;

}
```

Where x,y are event.getX(),event.getX() of imageview touch event

Comment: WTH does this response have to do w/ the question?