# Get color of ImageView

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to get the color ID of an `imageView` that I have set its color before.

```
ImageView im = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
im.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green);
```

How do I do this?

```
int colorId = im.getBackgroundColorResourceId() // how do I do this?
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339542/getting-the-background-color-of-an-imageview

Comment: I get this error: 
`(ColorDrawable) im.getBackground() = Cannot cast 'android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable' to 'android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable'`

Comment: It's... it's... `R.color.green`!!

Comment: I mean... you already know the color, since you set it. Or didn't I catch you?

Comment: I have multipile imageView, each with different color, for each imageView I want to get its own color id

Comment: The concept is the same. You **already know** their colors, since **you** assigned it. So, There's **really no need** to make the CPU work on this. With a clever programming, you can avoid to use the CPU without a real reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function in the `ImageView` class to retrieve the color of the `ImageView`, as they are not designed to be given a color but instead are designed to be given an image to display (hence the name, `ImageView`). If you want to be able to retrieve what color the `ImageView` has been set to, you could create your own custom `ImageView` class with the wanted functionality.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    int backgroundColor;

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        super.setBackgroundColor(color);
        backgroundColor = color;
    }

    public int getBackgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

This custom class, `CustomImageView`, will override the function `setBackgroundColor(int color)` and in doing so store the color to a variable as well as set the background color so that it can be retrieved later. The function `getBackgroundColor()` can be used to retrieve this variable.

This is not the simplest solution, and I am sure there are many others, but this one made the most sense to me.